# What is the name of this mouse behaviour?

Tags: mouseevent

There is a common behaviour (on Windows) when a pressed interface element is "activated" on mousedown, giving you the opportunity to not complete the click by moving the cursor away. If the mouse button is never released and the cursor brought back over the element, it will again be "activated" and ready to complete the mouse click.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

My question is - is there a name for this type of event/behaviour?

Comment: Downvoter: I understand this is not a classical question for SO, but it's quite specific and possibly has an exact answer (not opinion based).

Comment: There is no name that describes this as mouse event, because this is not really a mouse event but a UI behaviour. But you somehow could describe it as drag’n’drop where source and allowed target must be the same and the action is triggered on drop.

Comment: This is not an answer, since your question is ambiguous. However, doing anything to the mouse involves multiple events (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @t.niese I was afraid it'd be so.

Comment: @MichaelTracy I understand how it works - I have implemented it, which is why I'm looking for a name.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous but I believe your 'activation' would be on 'mouseover' (or hover) and your click would be completed on 'mouseup' (or click)

Perhaps you are talking about 'mouse capture' which is not an event at all but a behavior as @MichaelTracy has stated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture(v=vs.110).aspx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture

Comment: Please re-read the question. The key is keeping the mouse pressed after the initial mousedown.

Comment: Yes so pressing the mouse or not does not affect the hover and you will still 'activate' whether or not you are over the item.  If you then let the mouse up or complete the click the item's event will fire.  If your question is more detailed then this you should have included it in the description.